# Toggling between two font awesome icons

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to toggle between two font awesome icons fa-angle-right and fa-angle-down.

HTML Snippet

```js
let tagItem = document.getElementById('tag-item');
let angleCount = 0;
const angle = document.getElementById('angle-img');

tagItem.addEventListener('click',function(){

    if (angleCount %2 === 0) {
      angle.classList.remove('fa-angle-right');
      angle.classList.add('fa-angle-down');
    } else {
      angle.classList.remove('fa-angle-down');
      angle.classList.add('fa-angle-right');
    }
    
    angleCount++;
    console.log(angle.classList);
    
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<li id="tag-item" class="list-item">
<i class="fa fa-tag"></i><span id="tags">Tags</span><i id="angle-img" class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
</li>
```

I'm trying to toggle it for the TAG i with the ID 'angle-img'

Console Log proof that class is being toggled:

```
DOMTokenList(2) ["fa", "fa-angle-down", value: "fa fa-angle-down"]0: 
"fa"1: "fa-angle-down"length: 2value: "fa fa-angle-down"__proto__: 
DOMTokenList
DOMTokenList(2) ["fa", "fa-angle-right", value: "fa fa-angle-
right"]
base.html:303 DOMTokenList(2) ["fa", "fa-angle-down", value: "fa fa-
angle-down"]
```

The class is being toggled as required but the icon isn't toggling.
How can I toggle between those two images?

Comment: It appears to be functioning as intended, with the code provided, demonstrated here: https://jsfiddle.net/bf9wrxLw/

Comment: It doesn't work in my browser. Maybe ill just restart the live server and check it out.